# Snapshot version is different than Release versions in nexus

Tags: maven-2, jenkins

I am using maven and Jenkins, for some reason my Snapshot version is different than my Release versions in nexus. I expect them both to be same.
Any ideas

Comment: In which way they are different? The jar file differ cause the files is created at a different time which means the class files contain a different date etc. The information in the metainf file is different cause you have a different version etc. ? what do you really mean?

Answer (score 0):

How are the versions different?

A release version will be typically formatted ".." for instance; 1.0.4, whereas SNAPSHOT artifacts will be versioned as 1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.

If the x.y.z values are significantly different, check the local poms for the projects and make sure the versions are correct.

Try clearing out the workspace for the Jenkins job as there may be an incorrect POM left around from another build, are you using the maven release plugin? That may leave "relics" of changes after a build failure which could throw things out.